# Prove that $|p^2+2q^2-n|<\sqrt[4]{9n}$

Tags: number-theory, inequality

Prove that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}_+,\exists p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $|p^2+2q^2-n|<\sqrt[4]{9n}$

Solution. 
1) Assertion is true $\forall n\in[1,108]$
proof: Let $p\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$
If $n\in[3p^2,3p^2+2p+1)$ : 
$\min(n-(2p^2+p^2),(2p^2+(p+1)^2)-n)\le p<\sqrt[4]{27p^2}<\sqrt[4]{9n}$
If $n\in[3p^2+2p+1,3p^2+4p+2)$ : 
$\min(n-(2p^2+(p+1)^2),(2(p+1)^2+p^2)-n)\le p<\sqrt[4]{27p^2}<\sqrt[4]{9n}$
If $n\in[3p^2+4p+2,3(p+1)^2]$ : 
$\min(n-(2(p+1)^2+p^2),(2(p+1)^2+(p+1)^2)-n)\le p<\sqrt[4]{27p^2}<\sqrt[4]{9n}$
Q.E.D.

2) Assertion is true $\forall n\in [108,289]$
Proof:
Assertion is true $\forall n\in\{108,118\}$
$\min(n-(2.2^2+10^2),(2.3^2+10^2)-n)\le 5<\sqrt[4]{9\times 108}\le\sqrt[4]{9n}$

Assertion is true $\forall n\in\{118,129\}$
$\min(n-(2.3^2+10^2),(2.8^2+1^2)-n)\le 5<\sqrt[4]{9\times 118}\le\sqrt[4]{9n}$

Assertion is true $\forall n\in\{129,139\}$
$\min(n-(2.8^2+1^2),(2.3^2+11^2)-n)\le 5<\sqrt[4]{9\times 129}\le\sqrt[4]{9n}$

Assertion is true $\forall n\in\{139,150\}$
$\min(n-(2.3^2+11^2),(2.5^2+10^2)-n)\le 5<\sqrt[4]{9\times 139}\le\sqrt[4]{9n}$

Assertion is true $\forall n\in\{150,162\}$
$\min(n-(2.5^2+10^2),(2.3^2+12^2)-n)\le 6<\sqrt[4]{9\times 150}\le\sqrt[4]{9n}$

Assertion is true $\forall n\in\{162,172\}$
$\min(n-(2.3^2+12^2),(2.6^2+10^2)-n)\le 5<\sqrt[4]{9\times 162}\le\sqrt[4]{9n}$

Assertion is true $\forall n\in\{172,179\}$
$\min(n-(2.6^2+10^2),(2.7^2+9^2)-n)\le 3<\sqrt[4]{9\times 172}\le\sqrt[4]{9n}$

Assertion is true $\forall n\in\{179,187\}$
$\min(n-(2.7^2+9^2),(2.9^2+5^2)-n)\le 4<\sqrt[4]{9\times 179}\le\sqrt[4]{9n}$

Assertion is true $\forall n\in\{187,198\}$
$\min(n-(2.9^2+5^2),(2.1^2+14^2)-n)\le 5<\sqrt[4]{9\times 187}\le\sqrt[4]{9n}$

Assertion is true $\forall n\in\{198,209\}$
$\min(n-(2.1^2+14^2),(2.10^2+3^2)-n)\le 5<\sqrt[4]{9\times 198}\le\sqrt[4]{9n}$

Assertion is true $\forall n\in\{209,219\}$
$\min(n-(2.10^2+3^2),(2.5^2+13^2)-n)\le 5<\sqrt[4]{9\times 209}\le\sqrt[4]{9n}$

Assertion is true $\forall n\in\{219,228\}$
$\min(n-(2.5^2+13^2),(2.4^2+14^2)-n)\le 5<\sqrt[4]{9\times 219}\le\sqrt[4]{9n}$

Assertion is true $\forall n\in\{228,241\}$
$\min(n-(2.4^2+14^2),(2.6^2+13^2)-n)\le 6<\sqrt[4]{9\times 228}\le\sqrt[4]{9n}$

Assertion is true $\forall n\in\{241,251\}$
$\min(n-(2.6^2+13^2),(2.11^2+3^2)-n)\le 5<\sqrt[4]{9\times 241}\le\sqrt[4]{9n}$

Assertion is true $\forall n\in\{251,264\}$
$\min(n-(2.11^2+3^2),(2.2^2+16^2)-n)\le 6<\sqrt[4]{9\times 251}\le\sqrt[4]{9n}$

Assertion is true $\forall n\in\{264,275\}$
$\min(n-(2.2^2+16^2),(2.5^2+15^2)-n)\le 6<\sqrt[4]{9\times 264}\le\sqrt[4]{9n}$

Assertion is true $\forall n\in\{275,289\}$
$\min(n-(2.5^2+15^2),(2.12^2+15^2)-n)\le 7<\sqrt[4]{9\times 275}\le\sqrt[4]{9n}$

3) Assertion is true $\forall n\ge 290$
Proof: Let $p=\left\lfloor\sqrt{\frac{n-1}2}\right\rfloor$ so that $n\in\{2p^2+1,2(p+1)^2\}$
So $n\in[2p^2+k^2,2p^2+(k+1)^2)$ for some $k\in\{1,2,...,\left\lfloor\sqrt{4p+3}\right\rfloor\}$

And so $\min(n-2p^2-k^2,2p^2+(k+1)^2-n)\le k$ $\le \left\lfloor\sqrt{4p+3}\right\rfloor$

And so it remains to prove that :
$\left\lfloor\sqrt{4p+3}\right\rfloor<\sqrt[4]{9n}$ where $p=\left\lfloor\sqrt{\frac{n-1}2}\right\rfloor$

Enough to prove $\sqrt{4\sqrt{\frac{n-1}2}+3}<\sqrt[4]{9n}$, which is easily proved true $\forall n\ge 290$
Q.E.D.

I hope someone will post a nicer solution !

Comment: It is better to use \cdot than a period for multiplication.  In my first reading $2.3^2$ looked like $5.29$ (which you may write $5,29$), not $18$  You could also look at the recurrence for the Pell equation for finding $p,q$

Comment: compare Bambah and Chowla 1947  https://insa.nic.in/writereaddata/UpLoadedFiles/PINSA/Vol13_1947_2_Art05.pdf

Comment: Do you have any solution?